# Next.js - Loading doesn't turn off when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I'm building my portfolio in next.js, and in order to avoid showing partly loaded gallery images, I wanted to use a 'loading' state, which will turn off (become 0) once all the photos are loaded perfectly. It works just fine unless I refresh the page. The loading doesn't become 0 (false) when I refresh the page. When I change the category and come back, it again starts working fine. Only stops on the page whenever I refresh the page. What can be the problem?

P.S. When 'loading' is 1 (true) the opacity of the grid is 0.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import { GalleryLayoutStyle } from '../../style/componentStyles/GalleryLayoutStyle'
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-css'

const Gallery = ({ data }) => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(1)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const allImagesCount = data.length

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount((prev) => prev + 1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(1)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count == allImagesCount) {
      setLoading(0)
    }
  }, [count])


  return (
    <GalleryLayoutStyle loading={loading}>
      {loading == 1 ? <h1>Loading</h1> : null}
      <div className="grid">
        <Masonry className="my-masonry-grid" columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column">
          {data.map((item) => (
            <div className="gallery-box" key={item.id}>
              <img src={item.url} onLoad={increaseCount} />
              <div className="overlay">
                <div className="title">
                  <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                </div>
                <div className="zoom">
                  <img src="/icons/loupe.svg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Masonry>
      </div>
    </GalleryLayoutStyle>
  )
}

export default Gallery
```

Comment: you are setting loading to 1 and then immediately resetting it back to 0; which only relies on count; which, if allImagesCount ever changes, that condition will not be met

Comment: @DerekPollard i set it to 0 once all the photos are loaded, not immediately.

Comment: @DerekPollard it can't be outside of the function, it depends on the props the function gets.

Comment: I meant for you to add it to your useEffects 2nd param or take it out of the useEffect entirely

Comment: Since you're optimizing your useEffect, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders. Which is what you're describing

Comment: @DerekPollard Now I understand what you mean. Thanks a lot! You solved the problem :) Have a great day!

Comment: Glad I could help, I apologize for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

It looks (nearly) all fine to me.
I would change only one little thing. Don't set loading initially to 1, but 0. Make it depending only on `count`.

Maybe give it a try with this:

```
const Gallery = ({ data }) => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(0)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const allImagesCount = data.length

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount((prev) => prev + 1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === allImagesCount) {
      setLoading(0)
    }else{
      setLoading(1)
    }
  }, [count])
....
```